# Azure Function output binding with Azure.Cosmos.Table

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a simple azure function as below

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("MyTable")] CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var entity = new CustomerEntity("Jon", "Snow")
            {
                Email = "babc@email.com",
                PhoneNumber = "04026753432"
            };

            // Create the InsertOrReplace table operation
            TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);

            // Execute the operation.
            TableResult result = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
            CustomerEntity insertedCustomer = result.Result as CustomerEntity;

            // Get the request units consumed by the current operation. RequestCharge of a TableResult is only applied to Azure Cosmos DB
            if (result.RequestCharge.HasValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request Charge of InsertOrMerge Operation: " + result.RequestCharge);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello");
        }
    }
```

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table instead of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table. However the "Table" attribute is not being recognize. Is there any extension nuget that I need to include here ?

-Alan-

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to mix and match SDKs.  The binding that you are using in the function is not using the Cosmos version of the table SDK, so you either need to use the storage one outright, or not leverage a binding and just use the Cosmos Table SDK directly to create your own instance of a `cloudTable`

Answer (score 0):

Add Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage package and your done